# Zero delete votes remaining?

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-delete, 10k-tools

After voting to delete some questions via the 10k review tools, I came across this:

[image: zero votes remaining]

I casted the third delete vote, but the question still hasn't been deleted. It displays that there are zero votes remaining.

My theory is that the question's required delete vote threshold has decreased since I casted my vote. This is obviously related to the algorithm that calculates the votes required to delete a question based on the said question's net vote count.

Comment: For what it's worth, here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924476/what-do-i-need-to-do-besides-code) to the question.

Comment: I bet it used to require 4. Then it got enough downvotes to drop the requirement to 3. (note that the question was downvoted less than an hour ago) But it doesn't "recalculate" it at that point. So it will stay undeleted until the next vote.

Comment: It's been deleted now. Patience!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You and Mysticial are both correct - when you cast your delete vote, the question and its max-scored answer were at a total of 20, meaning it [required 4 delete votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/3).  Then a downvote occurred and lowered the delete threshold to 3.

I'll just update the /tools display to always show at least 1 vote required, as that's how the mechanic works.

Comment: Nice, so [meta-tag:status-completed]? If so, consider marking [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218494/0-more-votes-needed-to-delete-this-question) as well, though I claimed it's not a bug. (will edit now)

Comment: not yet.. I just checked in the fix for this.

Comment: @JarrodDixon - [tag:status-completed] this. I believe it's working as intended. If not, feel free to adjust tags.