# Are a user's comments deleted with their account?

Tags: support, comments, users, deleted-comments, deleted-users

Recently, a user made some comments on [one of my answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310323/suggest-a-question-for-the-2016-stack-overflow-developer-survey/310482#310482), as well as a few others. I checked back a few times and found that the user in question now no longer exists, and their comments are gone.

Is it standard practice to also delete a user's comments when they request for their account to be removed?

Comment: Not normally, check out the comments from user1864610 in [this Q+A](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256562/zero-delete-votes-remaining) for example.  Might have changed, I missed the memo.  Maybe the user requested deletion.

Comment: Are you sure you linked the right answer? The only deleted comment there that wasn't left by you was provided by a user who still has an active account.

Comment: @BradLarson Fairly sure. If you see my first comment on the linked answer, I mentioned another user (Trobbins). I checked a few other responses and saw similar situations; people responding to this person whose comments and account are not to be seen

Comment: @FuriousFolder - Oh, what happened there was they changed their username. That wouldn't change the @-responses to point to the new account. You'd have to remember that this used to be their name.

Comment: That's a strange situation. Thanks for following up on this :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, they are left behind and attributed to a generic "user12345"-style user. I know that I've had to sweep through later to find spam comments for a user that we destroyed as a spammer, but who had somehow gathered enough rep before then to post comments.

I'm more careful about checking out accounts now if there's a chance of this, and will manually delete comments as needed before account deletion.

Comment: are those generic accounts accessed from the moderator database? Or if somone flags a comment for some reason will it appear on the review tab?

Comment: @Korpel - The comments still act like normal comments. If someone flags them, they show up like any other. There's just no account attached to them.

Comment: @BradLarson is a deleted used defined as a user with a null userid ?

Comment: @BradLarson As in, would this query find all comments from deleted users? http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/399238/deleted-users-comments

Comment: @Matt not quite, but [this one](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/399243/deleted-users-comments) will.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Not all deleted users are appended with Userxxxxx

Comment: @Matt when a mod deletes the account the name is changed to userxxx. Likewise for user-deleted accounts. There are no other ways an account gets deleted.

Comment: @ArtOfCode what about this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482046/why-do-you-hate-sequences-on-oracle/482061#482061 in the comments

Comment: @Matt ah, I see what you mean. That's from an old system, when usernames were preserved. If you want those, then you can only query on null user ID. If not, the userxxx query is more semantically correct.

Comment: @ArtOfCode alse people could actually name their username userxxxx

Comment: @Matt ...which is why that query includes the user ID null check.

Comment: @ArtOfCode just seen that as i entered the comment :)